# Eclipse SVN Show all changes for author

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive

I am using both subversive and subclipse svn plug-ins and I was wondering if possible to show all the authors changes under the history. From what I can tell, under

`team -> show history`

It only display the top 25 recent history changes. How do I make it show all changes for a particular author? or can this not be done with eclipse?

Comment: [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) and [Subclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/subclipse) are separate plugins. Which are you using?

Comment: I have both installed

Comment: Subversion doesn't track history by author. Author is just one of the pieces of metadata attached to each commit. To do this, you'd have to retrieve the **full** log, then filter by author. This is potentially very expensive (time and bandwidth).

Comment: so I have to download svn tortoise for this?

Comment: Not sure how you reached the conclusion that you need TortoiseSVN for this.

Answer (score 2):

For the general case, as described by @alroc all metadata must be retrieved and filtered. This is described in the [why properties?](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.why) section of the svn book. See the box *Searchability (or, Why Not Properties)*.

In Subversive, from the history pane select *Show All*. After the history is retrieved you can apply a filter.

[image: Show All]

[image: Quick Filter]